# creating a rotating space in Chipmunk

Tags: chipmunk

I'm looking to make a small app in which a ball bounces around inside a square frame. Obviously thats simple enough to implement, but I would like the user to be able to rotate the frame manually (using the rotating gesture) as the ball is moving around. I have looked into using Chipmunk to accomplish this but it seems that its not possible to rotate a cpSpace, but only the bodies held within it.

My question is: Can such a process be implemented in Chipmunk by using cpBody objects, or woud i be wasting my time trying? Would it be easier to try and create my own system using things like bezierpaths with the containsPoint method?

Thanks for any help,

James

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at the "tumble" demo that comes with chipmunk. It sounds like it does pretty much what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! just trying to get the demos working now on Xcode, but im getting an error - 'OpenGL/gl.h' file not found - any ideas?

Comment: you should merge your 2 accounts